# Running Background java program

Tags: java, background-process

I am trying to make a java application which runs another java program at certain point of event occurrence . As I have to run this process in background I am using **&** symbol . This is part of the application .

```
private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
}

private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    // pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
}

runProcess("javac test2.java");
runProcess("java test2 "+id+" "+pass+" "+choice+" &");//Id,pass,choice are arguments of java program
```

The problem I am facing is If I am print the lines os that program my actual application does not move to next part until my background process is over which takes long time and if I omit these output lines then the background process exits and gives this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
```

And If I use  **pro.waitFor();**  then again the first problem .What should I do?

Comment: why not just run it in a another thread?  Do not need no `&` stuff

Comment: but I want it to run at a particular time in the java application. I am new to java programming ...would I be able to do this by runnning it in another thread?

Comment: Yes, put in in another thread.

Comment: Thanks can you provide some link how to do this..

Comment: an oldy but a goody http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html

Comment: You may also want to have a read through [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)